# Tkinter: update TopLevel window when closing another TopLevel window above first? (Reference?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm a python beginner making a program that is supposed to save and present reservations for a campingsite (just for fun...). I've structured it in an OOP-way meaning that I define a class for each seperate window. What I need to do is to update a TopLevel window (SubWindow2) presenting database entries, when another TopLevel window (created from Subwindow2) is closed.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MenuWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        #Widgets

    def open_subwindow1(self):
       self.window = Toplevel(self.master)
       self.SubSubWindow1 = SubSubWindow1(self.window)

    def open_subwindow2(self):
       self.window = Toplevel(self.master)
       self.SubSubWindow2 = SubSubWindow2(self.window)

class SubWindow1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
         self.master = master

         #Widgets

class Subwindow2(tk.TopLevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
         self.master = master

         #Widgets

         self.button = tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=open_subsub1)

    def load_values(self):
        #loading sqlite db-values into listboxes

    def open_subsub1(self):
        self.window = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.SubSubWindow1 = SubSubWindow1(self.window)

class SubSubWindow1(tk.TopLevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        #Widgets

        self.button = tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=on_quit)

    def on_quit(self):
        #Here I want to call a function that updates SubWindow2 (loads sqlite database values into several listboxes)

        self.master.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
myprog = MyProg(root)

root.mainloop()
```

How can i access a function in Subwindow2 from SubSubWindow1? `self.master` only refers to the `TopLevel()` instance right?

```
def on_quit(self):
    self.SubWindow2.load_values()
    self.master.destroy()
```

doesn't work, I get a `TypeError: unbound method load_values() must be called with SubWindow2 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Is this an unvalid approch to "nesting" TopLevel-windows? What's the alternative?

Any remarks are greatly appriciated! Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I should preface this by claiming that I am also a novice, and I would greatly appreciate the advice of others in order not to spread misinformation.

From what I can see, you have some misunderstandings with how inheritance vs. encapsulation works in Python. Firstly, within a Tkinter application, there should only be a single instance of Tk(). Within your class definitions, you declare...

```
class SubWindow1(tk.Tk):
```

This means that whenever you create a new SubWindow1, a new instance of Tk will become instantiated with it, and SubWindow1 will inherit all of its properties.

If you would like to create a class that refers to, and has all the properties, of a Toplevel instance, your Subwindow2 was correct.

```
class Subwindow2(tk.TopLevel):
```

However, within the **init**, you must also initialize this instance of Toplevel as so:

```
class SubWindow2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.master = master
```

Each 'master' refers to the element above it. Tk applications work as a tree hierarchy. This is why you should only have one instance of Tk(), which works as your 'root.' This instance of Tk contains windows within it, which contains windows or elements within them. So each window or element will have a parent, referred to as master, so you will be able to navigate around.

So when you create an instance of SubWindow2, this refers to everything within your SubWindow2, along with everything included in an instance of Toplevel. Because 'self' now refers to a Toplevel, you can pass it into the children to be a master, as such:

```
self.sub_sub_window1 = SubSubWindow1(self)
```

> self.master only refers to the TopLevel() instance right?

Yes, but since you will be inheriting all of the Toplevel attributes through your SubWindow2 inheritance, you can add on more methods and still refer to them through your self.master tag.

Lastly, you should also call pack() on elements that you would like to show up correctly on your windows.

Altogether, I've made some edits to your program to try and demonstrate some of the concepts of inheritance and how it works within a Tkinter application. I hope you can look at this and take something from it. Please let me know if there are any elements you disagree with, as it is nowhere near perfect.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MenuWindow():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.sub_window_1 = SubWindow1(self.master)
        self.sub_window_2 = SubWindow2(self.master)

class SubWindow1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.master = master

class SubWindow2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.master = master
        self.sub_sub_window1 = SubSubWindow1(self)

    def print_hello(self):
        print "Hello!"

class SubSubWindow1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.master = master
        self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text='Say Hello & Destroy', command=self.on_quit)
        self.button.pack()

    def on_quit(self):
        self.master.print_hello()
        self.master.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
myprog = MenuWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow this Works great trank you! Alltough I had to use "self" as a parent for my widgets (that is frames) in order for them to show up in the top window instead of the root window! Thank you for your help and effort